# Ignore and DoNotValidate not working for AutoMapper 8.1 and .NET Core 2.1

Tags: .net-core, automapper, azure-functions

I have developed an azure function in `.net core` and configured `automapper` in `startup.cs` by `builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType()));`

I am trying to create a map between domain class (table in EF core) and a DTO. The domain class has a property RowVersion . I want this property to be ignored while mapping dto to domain.

For this I created a Profile Class and created my custom map but this is not working.

I tried DoNotValidate , but it doesn't seem to work

**Startup.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType()));



   public class MapperProfile :Profile
    {
        public MapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<MyDto, MyDomain>().ForMember(i => i.RowVersion, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }
    }
```

**Service.cs**

```
_mapper.Map<myDomain>(myDtoInstance)
```

getting the below error

```
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters

 Unmapped properties:
[5/28/2019 7:00:40 AM] RowVersion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForMember` is used for referencing the destination objects, in your case, `MyDto`.

Use `ForSourceMember` instead:

```
public MapperProfile()
{
     CreateMap<MyDto, MyDomain>().ForSourceMember(i => i.RowVersion, opt => opt.Ignore());
}
```